# react-router get this.props.router from redux async action creator?

Tags: react-router, react-redux

using react-router 2.8.1 and `with-router` HOC

I can programmatically navigate by `this.props.router.push(url)`

I want to do that inside redux async action creator.
http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html#async-action-creators

I can get state from the async action creator, but not props.

How can I access the props?

Comment: Are you trying access props inside redux actions?

Comment: @AlessanderFrança Yes (action creators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need something inside your action creator that are not in the redux state, you'll need to pass it as parameter when you dispatch the action.

Not clear what data you need from the props but if you just want to do redirect in your action creator, you can just `import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'` and do a `browserHistory.push(url)`.